# Many Datagridview in one Itemssource MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagridview

I have MANY Datagridview (Automatic create Control (using Itemscontrol))

And One Items source (datas) from ICollection data;

How can I Binding Itemssource foreach datagridview with condition

EX:

datagridview1:  itemsource=datas WHERE datas.detailsID=1

datagridview2:  itemsource=datas WHERE datas.detailsID=2

...

IN XAML (Automatic Control)

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding datas}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding data}" />
                </WrapPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

IN ViewModel

ICollection Datas;
...

Comment: Sample code plz? More the information you give, it would be more easier to solve.

Comment: @CarbineCoder Sample added, please help :)

Comment: I assume your code is going to generate 1 datagridview for every detailsID. Then why do you need to add this Condition `WHERE datas.detailsID=1`?

Answer (score 1):

Why make things difficult for yourself? This is WPF and MVVM, so you simply split your original collection into however many data sources you need. Just define a collection property for each `ItemsSource` and populate them when you access the data for your original data collection. Then you simply data bind each property to their related `ItemSource` property.

---

UPDATE >>>

Let's say this is your original collection:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourDataType> collection = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> Collection
{
    get { return collection; }
    set { collection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Collection"); }
}
```

Make more collection properties - as many as you need:

```
private ObservableCollection<YourDataType> otherCollection = new ObservableCollection<YourDataType>();
public ObservableCollection<YourDataType> OtherCollection
{
    get { return otherCollection; }
    set { otherCollection = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("OtherCollection"); }
}
```

Populate them from the original collection in whatever way you need:

```
OtherCollection = Collection.Where(d => d.DetailsId == 1);
```

Now simply data bind your new collection properties to the various `DataGrid`s:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding OtherCollection}" />
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherCollection}" />
```

Comment: Oh, I'm a newbie, can you give me a sample or something relate?

Comment: So if I want to 10 GRID => 11 Collection?

Comment: Yes, with your original one not being displayed directly.

Comment: But Datagridview is auto generate?

Comment: Then use a `DataGrid` like you have shown in your code example.

Comment: Then I give up with helping you.

Comment: How can I change ItemsSource in XAML? (Because Datagrid is auto generate from ViewModel ?)